# Transcribe an Audio File in Python

Tags: python, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I'm trying to transcribe an audio file which is bit large. It's properties are as follows.

```
Size : 278.3 MB
Duration : 52 minutes
Format : WAV
```

Follwoing is my code which I used to convert it having 60 second durations. Could you please advice to transcribe this file at once?

```
import speech_recognition as sr

r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.AudioFile('sampleMp3.WAV') as source:
    audio = r.record(source, duration=60) 

command = r.recognize_google(audio)

text_file = open("Output.txt", "w")
text_file.write(command)
text_file.close()
```

Comment: Remove duration=60 or put the real total length there? Or process several parts in parallel, if that's what you meant?

Comment: @B. Go Tried the first one. It doesn't work. Will try parallel processing. Thank you!

Comment: @B. Go It doesn't work since the file is too large.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

speech_recognition python package is just a wrapper, it does not provide even basic functions.

If you want to use Google Speech API (paid), you can do something like this:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/speech/cloud-client/transcribe_async.py

If you want to consider Bing, it also provides similar API, see [How can I transcribe a speech file with the Bing Speech API in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47344310/how-can-i-transcribe-a-speech-file-with-the-bing-speech-api-in-python)

For the free alternative consider https://github.com/alumae/kaldi-offline-transcriber

Comment: @ Nikolay Shmyrev Thank you very much!

Comment: Tried Google Speech free and GCP version, bad results in both - finance context.

Answer (score -1):

Instead Of Transcirbing Using Python, Use Nuance Dragon Instead.

https://www.nuance.com/en-nz/dragon/dragon-anywhere/free-trial.html

The Best Transcribing Software.